# The view ecommerceapp.views.checkout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

I'm trying to build an ecommerce app and I'm building a form that when a particular payment option is clicked, the url is pointed to a particular one. But whenever I try to run the website, this error pops out:

```
The view ecommerceapp.views.checkout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Views.ps

```
def checkout(request):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = checkoutForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # here is the place where your find the values in:
                if form.cleaned_data['payment_option'] == 'Stripe':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='Stripe')
                elif form.cleaned_data['payment_option'] == 'Paypal':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='Paypal')

            return redirect(reverse('core:index'))

        else:
            form = checkoutForm()

        return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/checkout.html', {'form': form,'items': OrderItem.objects.all(), 'orders': Order.objects.all()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing some function-based and class-based view concepts. Specifically, your `get` sub-function is never getting called. You should remove it:

```
def checkout(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = checkoutForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # here is the place where your find the values in:
            if form.cleaned_data['payment_option'] == 'Stripe':
                return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='Stripe')
            elif form.cleaned_data['payment_option'] == 'Paypal':
                return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='Paypal')
         return redirect(reverse('core:index'))
     else:
        form = checkoutForm()
     return render(request, 'ecommerceapp/checkout.html', {'form': form,'items': OrderItem.objects.all(), 'orders': Order.objects.all()})
```